# Can my app, which relies on time-bound operations as its main functionality, safely use the USE_EXACT_ALARM?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-permissions, foreground-service

I have developed an app that includes a record feature, allowing users to capture audio for a maximum duration of 30 minutes. Users also have the option to manually stop the recording before the 30-minute mark. To ensure uninterrupted recording when the app is placed in the background, I have implemented a foreground service. This service is managed by an alarm manager, which is responsible for stopping the recording after 30 minutes.

However, I have encountered an issue specifically on devices running Android 12 and above. The alarm manager fails to stop the service as expected in these cases. In response to this problem, Google has introduced a new feature called USE_EXACT_ALARM in Android 33. The official documentation states that **this feature is primarily intended for apps that heavily rely on precise timing, such as alarm clocks or calendars.**

Considering the nature of my app, which heavily relies on audio recording as its primary functionality, I am unsure if using USE_EXACT_ALARM would be appropriate. I am concerned that utilizing this feature might result in the revocation of necessary permissions for audio recording. Since recording audio is a critical feature of my app, and all other functionalities depend on it, I need to determine whether I can safely utilize USE_EXACT_ALARM without facing permission-related issues.